# JS input type date field, keep values selected after form submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

Is there a way for the

```
<input type="date" id="from" class="mdl-textfield__input" name="from" value="{{moment date=d format='YYYY-MM-DD'}}" style="position:relative; float: left; width: 180px; bottom: 10px;"/>
```

field to remember selected value after form submission?

Comment: Do you want to keep permanently or temporarily?

Comment: Temporarily, so that the selected date is showed after the form is sendt

Comment: You can store it in a global variable, if it is not available your current model

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the HTML5 Local Storage to save the date after the submit. 
This is how you can do it:

> **1) Add to your form onsubmit function:**

```
<form onsubmit="setDate()">
```

> **2) Create Setter and Getter functions to the date:**

```
    function setDate(){
        var value = document.getElementById('from').value;
        localStorage.setItem("user_selected_date", value); 
    }
    function getDate(){
        if (localStorage.getItem("user_selected_date") === null) {// Check if there is selected date. 
              return "{{moment date=d format='YYYY-MM-DD'}}"; 
        }
        return localStorage.getItem("user_selected_date");
    }
```

> **3) Set the value to your input:**

```
document.getElementById('from').value = getDate();
```

Comment: Yes this is very nice ;) i suppose i can do the same for the "to" date filed as well. Thank you

Comment: This worked for me with Django templates and with a non date input field too. E.g. my GET function returned "" for if condition as opposed to the date.

Answer (score 1):

i guess you want something like this ? :

stored the value in a variable after clicking the submit button. you can do whatever you want with that variable

```js
$("#submit").click(function(){


var dateStore = $("input[type='date']").val()
alert(dateStore)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="from" class="mdl-textfield__input" name="from" value="{{moment date=d format='YYYY-MM-DD'}}" style="position:relative; float: left; width: 180px; bottom: 10px;"/>
<button type="submit" id="submit">
Submit
</button>
```

Comment: Yes thank you for nice response! :) i can certainly use this :)

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML5 with storage
   stored the value in a variable after clicking the submit button. you can do whatever you want with that variable

```
localStorage.setItem("user_selected_date", value);
```