# How to persist range control value on page reload

Tags: html, django

I have a `Django` application in which I want to persist `range control` value on page reload. At the moment on every page reload its value is getting reset to the default. I know `HTTP` is a `stateless protocol` and consider every request as new, So we have to find some way to store range value in a `cookie` or something like that and then retrieve it from clients machine on page reload somewhat like [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-persist-checkbox-checked-state-after-page-reload/). Can anybody show me the right direction, thanks in advance.

```
<div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" name="myRange" id="myRange">
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930144/keep-input-value-after-refresh-page

Comment: @YannicHamann Thanks it worked