# Save <input> and after refresh keep the value in the <input>

Tags: javascript, html

I have `<input type='number'>` and I am saving it to localStorage.
But after refresh the value inserted before refresh did not remain saved.
Is there a way to keep value saved?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930144/keep-input-value-after-refresh-page

Comment: Please show the code where you are saving it to local storage. Note that you'll also need code to pull it out of local storage and populate the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Set and Get Local Storage using JavaScript

*Set value in local Storage*

```
localStorage.setItem("localStorageValue", "local Storage value");
```

*Get value from local storage*

```
localStorage.getItem("localStorageValue");
```