# How to display the date field in input box after submitting the form in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, form-submit, datefield

I need to display the user-selected date in the input box on the same page once the form gets submitted.
I was referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38844743/js-input-type-date-field-keep-values-selected-after-form-submission/38845803) link and if I try to implement the same in my code, my form is not getting submitted and am not able to see the desired output.

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<form method="POST" id="myform">
<div class="de-section de-cart-stat d-flex align-items-center flex-wrap mt-4">
StartDate:<input type="date" id="stdate" name="stname">
EndDate:<input type="date" id="eddate" name="edname">
<button id="submitbtn" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#submitbtn").click(function() {
 if ($("#stdate").val().length === 0 || $("#eddate").val().length === 0) {
   $("#errorModal").modal("show");
   return false;
  }
  else{
     $("form").submit();
}
});
```

Any ideas to display the dates in the input box after clicking the submit button using javascript.?

Comment: _my form is not getting submitted and am not able to see the desired output._ is there any error message?

Comment: @Kristian No error message. Because the form was not submitted, the selected dates were not passing to the backend scripts and I'm getting only null values instead of selected dates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your cake and eat it too, use AJAX

```js
$("#myform").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop submission 
  if ($("#stdate").val().length === 0 || $("#eddate").val().length === 0) {
    $("#errorModal").modal("show");
    return;
  }
  $.post("someUrl",$(this).serialize(),function(res) {
    $("someContainer").html(res)
  });  
});
```